# How to manage many (>500) background URLSession downloads with AFNetworking 2.x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have an app on the app store that uses AFNetworking 2.x to download large files in the background with NSURLSession-based downloads, because the user will often put the app in the background (it gets terminated after a while of course, but the downloads finish all the same. Wonderful). This app is working well. Usually users are only downloading a few files at a time.

Now I need to make another similar app, but this time instead of a few large files, it is very likely that the user will want to download a large number of smallish files: for example, 500 files that are 1-5mb each. Again, the app will often be put in the background, so I want to stay with NSURLSessionDownloadTask unless there's a really good reason not to.

**My question is, can I simply create 500 NSURLSessionDownloadTasks all at once?** Does AFNetworking do some clever throttling so as not to overload the system? Or does iOS do it? Or does nothing do it, and I have to painfully track & organize the state of transfers across restarts of my app (ie. because it gets put in the background eventually terminated) ?

If anyone knows the limits of how many NSURLSessionDownloadTasks you can create reliably simultaneously, that would be awesome...
thanks!

p.s. I greatly prefer obj-c to swift, thx :)

Comment: Post this question to the internal Apple Forums in Networking - you'll get a definitive answer.

Comment: Isn't it posible to make a .zip with the selected files on your server and handle it internally?

Comment: @BenjaminJimenez the server is not mine

Comment: @DavidH I'm not sure where you mean, where are the internal apple forums? Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: @xaphod https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/core-os/networking

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked (haven't looked at the iOS 9 betas), task creation was unexpectedly expensive and also superlinear. On my test runs:

- 50 tasks -> ~1.5s
- 200 tasks -> ~11.5s
- 500 tasks -> ~55s

Since my file count was often a 5-digit number, scheduling everything at once wasn't a solution for me. My approach (which isn't in production yet, I stopped working on the feature in favour of other things), combines persistence with `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` and uses the session identifiers to sort out which logical download a particular file belongs to. Further downloads are scheduled from one of the delegates depending on whether I'm on the normal lifecycle or coming from `-application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` (debugging this situation can get painful; `NSUserDefaults` is your friend). The theory seems sound, I can see that tasks do get scheduled, but I'm currently stuck getting the iOS downloader daemon to conform to my will.

If the server-side zip as suggested by Benjamin Jimenez is an option for you, do yourself a favour and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks Kyo that's helpful. So if I understood right, you're scheduling some tasks up front, then when they complete you're scheduling more. Using this approach did you find it possible to schedule additional NSURLSessionDownloadTasks while your app is in the background (ie. via `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`) ?  What are the other pitfalls (ie. where doesn't the daemon conform to your will) ?  Sadly, server-side zip is not possible in this case. What i'm worried about is that the user has to keep opening the app again and again, just to even START the transfers. Bleck...

Comment: That's the gist of it. I'm able to schedule from background even if my app was just launched by iOS to deal with the events. iOS gives you about 30s to do that, if you don't call the provided completion handler by then, bang! The problem with the daemon (tasks scheduled from background take too long to run) may or may not be alleviated by tweaking the session configuration. Another pitfall is all the tracking that has to be done by hand, and some common assumptions that may not hold when launched in background (in my case, CoreData put a private queue context on the "main thread").

Comment: All you have to go by when the app is launched to handle events is the session identifier and the _source_ URLs, so whatever structure you have needs to be able to build context just from that. And the moment you call the completion handler, iOS puts the app to sleep, it's something to watch out for if you use a lot of dispatch_async().

Comment: Thanks Kyo. Yup i'm familiar with rebuilding state via the session identifier and source URL... can you tell me more about "tasks scheduled from background take too long to run" ? Do you mean that you CAN schedule tasks from the background, but when you start them via `resume`, it is a long time until they actually start? Is it at least reliable that the task eventually starts, or does the user have to open the app for it to start sometimes? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't investigated the issue extensively since I was ordered to work on more urgent features, but from what I saw, tasks are created and I call `-resume` on them. If I remember right, tasks do start, sometimes after several hours, and they may actually fail depending on how your session's timeouts are set. In practice I ended up opening the app to get downloads going again. I thought iOS would hurry up and run my tasks if I used small timeouts but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'll try to run a clean test tonight.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking to an apple rep on this thread, he talks about the rate limiter there and on another thread. I just posted my approach i'm planning to use.... https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11621

Answer (score 1):

The Apple staff member "eskimo" on apple developer forums helped me find the answer, which you can see in this forum post:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11621

Pasting here the relevant parts:

> (me) I've read through this thread and the one you linked to here
> (https://devforums.apple.com/message/938057#938057) and I have a
> question about best practices to download 10,000-20,000 files via
> NSURLSessionDownloadTasks. (Disclaimer, i'm using AFNetworking 2.x).
> I'm targeting iOS 8 and newer, so answers do not have to work on iOS
> 7.   How can we compute a reasonable batch (group) size ? I understand the resume-rate limiter means one wants the batch size to be higher,
> but there's an unknown max limit of simultaneous task requests that
> will crash the daemon.
>
> (me) My assumption here is that when the user opens my app and it runs
> for some time in the foreground, then the rate limiter is "reset" or
> similar -- so now things will flow nicely again. Is this assumption
> correct?
>
> (eskimo) Yes. Also, starting with iOS 8, if the user brings your app
> to the front then iOS will automatically give tasks a 'kick'.  I've
> forgotten the exact mechanics of this but I'm pretty sure it's covered
> in [WWDC 2014 Session 707 What's New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/).